# Mostrar un formulario y JTable en un JInternalFrame

Tags: java, java-swing

estoy intentando agregar un Formulario (3 JTextFiel y 2 JButtons) y 1 JTable en el mismo JInternalFrame.. Sin embargo solo puedo mostrar el Formulario o la Tabla (incompleta).

He intentado agregarla con 2 Panels, uno para el formulario y otro para la tabla, el resultado es el siguiente:

```
String[] columnStudents = {
      "Nombre", "Curso", "Calificacion",
    };
    Object[][] dataStudents = {
      {"Juanito", "Español", "6"},
      {"Pepito", "Ciecias", "7"},
      {"Albterto", "Historia", "8"},
    };
    JTable tableStudent = new JTable(dataStudents, columnStudents);
    printDataStudent(tableStudent);

    JScrollPane scrollPane_student = new JScrollPane();
    JInternalFrame_student.add(scrollPane_student, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    JPanel JPanel_student = new JPanel();
    JPanel_student.add(labelName);
    JPanel_student.add(textfieldName);
    JPanel_student.add(labelCourse);
    JPanel_student.add(textfieldCourse);
    JPanel_student.add(labelScore);
    JPanel_student.add(textfieldScore);
    JPanel_student.add(btnAddStudent);
    JPanel_student.add(btnDeleteStudent);

    JPanel JPanel_tableStudent = new JPanel();
    JPanel_tableStudent.add(tableStudent, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JInternalFrame_student.add(JPanel_student);
    JInternalFrame_student.add(JPanel_tableStudent);
```

Y esto es lo que me muestra:
[image: Imagen del primer intento]

Después, intente usar el mismo scrollPane para agregar ahi la tabla sin embargo, obtengo este resultado:

Codigo

```
JTable tableStudent = new JTable(dataStudents, columnStudents);
    tableStudent.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500,70));
    tableStudent.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    printDataStudent(tableStudent);
    JScrollPane scrollPane_student = new JScrollPane(tableStudent);
    
    JInternalFrame_student.add(scrollPane_student, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JPanel JPanel_student = new JPanel();
    JPanel_student.add(labelName);
    JPanel_student.add(textfieldName);
    JPanel_student.add(labelCourse);
    JPanel_student.add(textfieldCourse);
    JPanel_student.add(labelScore);
    JPanel_student.add(textfieldScore);
    JPanel_student.add(btnAddStudent);
    JPanel_student.add(btnDeleteStudent);
    
    JInternalFrame_student.add(JPanel_student);
```

[image: Segundo intento]

¿Alguna idea de porque no puede mostrarse ambos en el InternalFrame?

Comment: Estas cerca, crea un `JPanel` con `BorderLayout` lo pones en la ventana interna y después a ese panel es a quien le vas a agregar la tabla en el centro (`BorderLayout.CENTER`) y el formulario debajo (`BorderLayout.SOUTH`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BorderLayout tiene 5 áreas, y cada área no puede tener mas de un componente.  Cuando usas el método `add()` sin restricciones (segundo argumento) el componente (primer argumento) se irá al área central, la cual tenderá a ocupar el máximo espacio posible ya que es donde va el componente preponderante.
De tal manera que cuando haces el segundo `add` a `JInternalFrame_student` estas sustituyendo el componente existente, y ocupa todo el espacio.

Prueba lo siguiente:

```
    JTable tableStudent = new JTable(dataStudents, columnStudents);
    printDataStudent(tableStudent);

    JScrollPane scrollPane_student = new JScrollPane(tableStudent);

    JPanel JPanel_student = new JPanel();
    ...

    JInternalFrame_student.add(scrollPane_student, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    JInternalFrame_student.add(JPanel_student, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
```

Comment: Quedo, muchas gracias... Me faltó leer acerca de BorderLayout y sus areas. Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Una pregunta... Si deseo agregar otra tabla en el InternalFrame, como lo haria? Que sea Tabla -Tabla Botones.. De arriba a abajo, claro.

Comment: Coloca las dos tablas en un panel con BoxLayout.